# Inside of the Try block doesnt return anything

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, try-catch, html-agility-pack

I am trying html-scraping for fun and my question is.
This Response.write() method works from inside the try catch block on IDE.
But it doesnt return the Response.write() method on the server.

```
try
          {
            if (x == 1)
            {
                Url = "https://www.**********.com/" + arama;
            }
            else
            {
                Url = "https://www.**********.com/" + arama + "?pagingOffset=" + y;
            }

            doc = web.Load(Url);
            liste = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[1]/a")[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
            Url = "https://www.**********.com" + liste;
            doc = web.Load(Url);
            liste = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"classifiedDetail\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h5")[0].InnerText;
            liste2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"phoneInfoPart\"]/li/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
            count++;
            liste = liste.ToUpper();
            Response.Write(count + " - " + liste + " Tel: " + liste2 + "</br>");
        }
        catch { }
```

in short this web app using HtmlAgilityPack to find html values by their xpath and I use Response.write() to return the inside value while innertext() converts it to string for me.

Comment: Start by avoiding empty catch blocks that silently swallow any exception. I strongly suspect that an exception is being thrown, but you can't tell what because your code effectively says "I don't care if this didn't work. No-one needs to know what went wrong."

Comment: it says = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Right, so you're getting a NullReferenceException. You should look at the stack trace to find out why, and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: how do i read stack trace while the website on anotherhosting. because when i work with ide i dont get this error.

Comment: Well you've found out that the *message* is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - so however you got *that* information, just get it to show you the whole exception instead of just the message.

Comment: does this message related to the matter with any way? = "An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. "

Comment: Well yes - it's saying that an exception is being thrown, so the request isn't completing properly...

Comment: yeah i narrowed it down a little bit and found the problem. I have no idea how to solve this one yet. soo there is this  Line 51: doc = web.Load(html);
it suppose to load the html url to doc which is HtmlDocument type. My guess html string did not proparly rendered as suppose to be? i have the url like this... var html = @"https://www.MyName.com/" + arama;

Comment: Please don't start asking extra questions in comments. If that line is throwing the exception directly, then `web` is probably null - and we have no idea where that comes from. It sounds like you have more diagnostics work to do.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you get an exception in your web.Load call and it hits your empty catch? Try putting a Response.Write into your catch that just writes out "BOOM". Or better yet, write out the exception.

Comment: turns out to be the try catch works perfectly just doesnt return the response.write method. i need to print those values but how?